# Should HTTPS work automatically on my website or does it need to be allowed somehow?

Tags: tls, http

If I simply type in `security.stackexchange.com` into my browsers URL bar, it uses  HTTPS to fetch data from the server.

Is it possible for a website to not work over HTTPS? Does it have to be configured manually from the server side by the owner of the website, or does it just work automatically for all websites?

Comment: Are you asking if it's recommended to 301 redirect to the HTTPS version of a site?

Comment: Please clarify what do you mean : `Is it possible that one of the website - not working with HTTPS`

Comment: [This meta post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/345012/https-its-time) and its links give you a brief outline of what was required to HTTPS-ify Stackexchange. Although small and unimportant websites with few users are often easier.

Comment: The question is about to ask that this is normal or not normal if a webpage is working with 'http://' but not working 'https:// '. 

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whether HTTP and HTTPS work at all depends on your hosting provider. Almost all hosting providers provide a HTTP version of a site, but not all providers support HTTPS. If you try to connect to https://yoursite.com/ you may get an error message:

- "Connection refused" indicates that the server does not support HTTPS at all. Your browser tries to connect on port 443, but the server does not accept connections on that port.
- "Your connection is not secure" indicates that the server does support HTTPS, but it does not provide the correct certificate for your site.

Sites that support HTTPS may want users to always use the HTTPS version, and never the HTTP version. There are some ways to ensure this:

- If the user connects to HTTP, immediately redirect them to the HTTPS version.
- On the HTTPS version, respond with a Strict-Transport-Security header to indicate that HTTPS should be used from now on.